# How to redirect user to the referrer page after login is successful in jquery php?

Tags: php, jquery

How to redirect page after login is successful in JQUERY ajax PHP ? My script don't work! Can I use header("Location:url") in php.  My username and password  are matched but not redirect to the referrer url.

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['usrname'])&&isset($_POST['usrpass']))
    {
           $usrname=str_replace(" ","",stripslashes(trim($_POST['usrname'])));
          $usrpass=sha1(str_replace("                ","",stripslashes(trim($_POST['usrpass']))));
        $Lgn=$con->prepare("select * from admin where username=? and   password=?");
        $Lgn->bindParam(1,$usrname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Lgn->bindParam(2,$usrpass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $Lgn->execute();
        if($Lgn->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$Lgn->fetch())
            {
                extract($row);
                if(!empty($aid))
                {
                    $_SESSION['admin_id']=$aid;
                    $_SESSION['usrname']=$username;
                    $_SESSION['usrpass']=$password;
                    echo "match";
                }else
                {
                    echo 'no match';
                }
            }
        }else
        {
            echo 'Fail login';
        }

     }
```

**Jquery Script**

```
  function loginbtn()
 {
 $(".logininfo").css("display","block");
 $(".logininfo").html('<img src="icon/loader.gif" width="100">');
 var usrname=$("#usrname").val();
 var usrpass=$("#usrpass").val();
 var login="usrname="+usrname+"&usrpass="+usrpass;
 if(usrname==='' || usrpass==='')
 {
     $(".logininfo").text('နောက်တစ်ကြိမ်ပြန်စစ်ပေးပါ');
 }else
 {
     $.ajax({
        url:"authorized/ajax/process.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: login,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data!=='match')
        {
        $(".logininfo").html(data);
        $("#usrname").val('');
        $("#usrpass").val('');
        }else
        {
            window.location.href= "https://www.google.com";
        }
    }
     });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use header("Location: redirect_page.php");

I you want to do it using java script, try to return a json to front-end instead of echo. Then you can do whatever you want in the front-end javascript.

for an example for login success scenario, you can do like this in the php script.

```
return json_encode(['login'=>true]);
```

then you can catch the response in javascript and do the redirect to the page you want.

```
success: function(data)
{
    if(data.login==true){
        //redirect to login success page
    }
}
```